# How are commercial psychometric instruments or content protected legally?

Tags: measurement, mbti

I understand the Myers–Briggs Type Indicator (MBTI) is registered.

What are the limitations for individuals and other business wishing to utilise the MBTI without a license to do so.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I believe that the tools are generally protected in the same way as anything else under copyright law, unless otherwise stated.  As for the content of any test, that would come under patient confidentiality laws

Comment: As per the tag description, MBTI is pseudoscience.  Perhaps try a question without reference to a non-scientific psychometric.

Comment: whether MBTI is pseudoscience or not is irrelevant. i have been in situations where I wanted to use the BDI for depression and was warned against doing so, that i would be sued etc. the question may need rewording, but i think it's of merit.